# One Class SVM fails on classifying training set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm currently working on a project to classify windows of time series as outliners/inliners with OCSVM. While doing some testing i stumbled upon the following problem/question:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> train = [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)]
... 
>>> clf = svm.OneClassSVM()
... 
>>> clf.fit(train)
OneClassSVM(cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
      max_iter=-1, nu=0.5, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
      verbose=False)
>>> clf.predict(train)
array([-1, -1,  1])
```

Why does the classifier fail here? -1 means outliner... but im predicting the training set? So everything should be 1 (inliner).

What do i miss? Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html), it seems that the `nu` parameter which is 0.5 by default gives a bound on the training errors and support vectors and since 0.5*3(training examples) is 1.5, the training continues till there are one or two examples correctly classified.

Tweaking the `nu` value should help you classify more points but you may risk overfitting.